# StorageFileQueryResults.ContentsChanged not fired

Tags: vb.net, windows-8, windows-runtime, tablet, filesystemwatcher

I try to develop a simple (and first) Windows 8 app for my new surface. Within this app I try to watch a folder for adding new files (especially pictures). For this I try to use the event StorageFileQueryResults.ContentsChanged.

The code is quite simple, but the event isn't firing when I add a new file. Here is the code:

```
    'Load Image Libary Pictures
    Dim fqFiles = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileQuery()
    AddHandler fqFiles.ContentsChanged, AddressOf ContentsChanged
    Dim liFiles = Await fqFiles.GetFilesAsync()

Private Sub ContentsChanged(sender As IStorageQueryResultBase, args As Object)
    Dim msgDialog = New MessageDialog("Test", "test2")
    msgDialog.ShowAsync()
End Sub
```

Has anyone an idea if I got something wrong?

Comment: I droped a new picture into the folder. I have to say I an Surface Pro with an Windows 8 (not RT).

Comment: Additionaly I tried it now with remote debugging on the surface and pushed the files via network to the device.

Comment: I am not sure if this is something that would work in metro app, considering that apps get suspended 5 seconds after they go into background.

Comment: Thanks for this advise. I know, that this won't work in suspending mode, but that not nessesary. It's important for me to work in active mode. Until I have an solution I will poll the folder to check if there are new files.